# Pivot wider using multiple columns that contain the same values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a tibble that contains some paired values spread across multiple columns as follows

```
tbl <- tibble(
    p1 = c('Q5SIJ9', 'Q5SIJ9', 'Q5SIJ9', 'Q5SIJ9', 'Q5SIJ9', 'Q5SIJ9', 'K7UUB6', 'A2ZBY1', 'A0A1L8ELU3', 'A2XXE3'),
    o1 = c('THET2', 'THET2', 'THET2', 'THET2', 'THET2', 'THET2', 'MAIZE', 'ORYSI', 'XENLA', 'ORYSI'),
    p2 = c('A0A674MM40', 'Q8AXY6', 'A0A1D5NX49', 'Q62838', 'Q7QIP0', 'Q61006', 'Q5SIJ9', 'Q5SIJ9', 'Q5SIJ9', 'Q5SIJ9'),
    o2 = c('TAKRU', 'CHICK', 'CHICK', 'RAT', 'ANOGA', 'MOUSE', 'THET2', 'THET2', 'THET2', 'THET2')
)
```

This is what it looks like

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   p1         o1    p2         o2   
   <chr>      <chr> <chr>      <chr>
 1 Q5SIJ9     THET2 A0A674MM40 TAKRU
 2 Q5SIJ9     THET2 Q8AXY6     CHICK
 3 Q5SIJ9     THET2 A0A1D5NX49 CHICK
 4 Q5SIJ9     THET2 Q62838     RAT  
 5 Q5SIJ9     THET2 Q7QIP0     ANOGA
 6 Q5SIJ9     THET2 Q61006     MOUSE
 7 K7UUB6     MAIZE Q5SIJ9     THET2
 8 A2ZBY1     ORYSI Q5SIJ9     THET2
 9 A0A1L8ELU3 XENLA Q5SIJ9     THET2
10 A2XXE3     ORYSI Q5SIJ9     THET2
```

Values in `p1` and `p2` are pairs and each of them are associated with the respective values in `o1` and `o2`

I want to pivot wider using multiple columns with the column names coming from the columns `o1` and `o2` and the values coming from `p1` and `p2`. However, if you notice, some of the values in column `p1` and `p2` are the same (including their corresponding entries for `o1` and `o2`).

How do I pivot wider such that I get the following table?

```
# A tibble: 1 × 9
  THET2  TAKRU      CHICK              RAT    ANOGA  MOUSE  MAIZE  ORYSI          XENLA     
  <chr>  <chr>      <chr>              <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>          <chr>     
1 Q5SIJ9 A0A674MM40 Q8AXY6, A0A1D5NX49 Q62838 Q7QIP0 Q61006 K7UUB6 A2ZBY1, A2XXE3 A0A1L8ELU3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `pivot_longer` to get the data in long format, do a group by `summarise` and then `transpose` (from `data.table`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tbl %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c(".value", "grp"), 
      names_sep = "(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])") %>%
    group_by(o) %>%
    summarise(p = toString(unique(p))) %>% 
    data.table::transpose(make.names = "o")
```

-output

```
 ANOGA              CHICK  MAIZE  MOUSE          ORYSI    RAT      TAKRU  THET2      XENLA
1 Q7QIP0 Q8AXY6, A0A1D5NX49 K7UUB6 Q61006 A2ZBY1, A2XXE3 Q62838 A0A674MM40 Q5SIJ9 A0A1L8ELU3
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! Can you please explain the regex a little bit?

Comment: @GAURAVDIWAN it ist a regex lookaround to specify the names separation should be between a lower case letter and a digit i.e. o1 or o2, it should be split between o and 1 or o and 2, and the `names_to` '.value' will get the value of column in 'o' and 'grp' gets the number 1 or 2

Answer (score 0):

```
tbl_1 <- tbl %>%
  select(p1, o1)

tbl_2 <- tbl %>%
  select(p1 = p2,
         o1 = o2)

tbl_out <- bind_rows(tbl_1, tbl_2) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(o1) %>%
  summarize(vals = toString(unique(p1))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = o1,
              values_from = vals)

knitr::kable(tbl_out)


|ANOGA  |CHICK              |MAIZE  |MOUSE  |ORYSI          |RAT    |TAKRU      |THET2  |XENLA      |
|:------|:------------------|:------|:------|:--------------|:------|:----------|:------|:----------|
|Q7QIP0 |Q8AXY6, A0A1D5NX49 |K7UUB6 |Q61006 |A2ZBY1, A2XXE3 |Q62838 |A0A674MM40 |Q5SIJ9 |A0A1L8ELU3 |
```